# Android Studio move project from Eclipse to SVN

Tags: android, svn, intellij-idea, import

I have been developing an Android project on Eclipse and have used SVN with tortoise to backup the project.

I have recently moved to Android Studio and imported the project from Eclipse.  I have also made extensive edits in Android Studio.

Now I want to use SVN on Intellij. I have looked for help on setting up SVN on Intellij and committing the updated files.

I have not been able to find basic help on doing this. What I have found is information that assumes you know all there is to know on SVN, setting up Intellij and committing edits. My knowledge is scratchy so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Subversion integration in Settings | Version Control. Once you do that, you will see the list of the files you've modified in the Changes view (you can use VCS | Show Changes View to display it easily). From there, you commit changes by selecting specific files or an entire changelist and invoking the "Commit Changes" action from the context menu.

You can find a basic introduction on working with version control in IntelliJ IDEA [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control-basics.html).

If you have made changes in a directory which was not controlled by Subversion, then you need to check out your Subversion repository to a separate clean directory (VCS | Check out from version control | Subversion, [see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/checking-out-files-from-subversion-repository.html) for more details), then copy the changed state of your project to the directory you've checked out (overwriting all the files there). Then you'll be able to commit your changes as described above.

Comment: Thanks yole. Before i made edits on Android Studio, I had not imported from SVN.  Your answer assumes I had done that so it is useful for me in the future.I had made extensive edits in Eclipse before moving the edited files to Android Studio.

Comment: Edited the answer to describe this case as well. In general, if your project is under a VCS, you always need to perform the changes in a directory which is managed by the VCS and with the VCS integration enabled. This ensures that the history is correctly preserved for all changes, including file moves and renames.

Comment: Thanks for your help yole.  I am more familiar with Tortoise and I was confused by the options and errors I got in Studio so I decided to continue with Tortoise.

Comment: Which errors did you get? In general, the big disadvantage to not having the VCS integration in IntelliJ is that the history will not be correctly preserved when you copy, move or rename files.

Comment: I got SVN client old and unregistered GIT root. Besides, I did not have the experience to know which options to set up in file|settings|Project settings|version control or VCS|Subversion.